# Create one 'list' by userID

Tags: python, sorting

I want to create a list per user so i got this jsonfile:

```
 data =  [
    {
      "id": "1",  
      "price": 1,   
    }, 
    {  
      "id": "1", 
      "price": 10,  
    }, 
    {
      "id": "2", 
      "price": 3, 
    }, 
    {   
      "id": "1", 
      "price": 10, 
    }, 
    {  
      "id": "2",   
      "price":8,  
    }, 
  ]
```

I'm on python and I want to have a result like
for the user with `'id':1` [1,10,10]

and for the user with `"id": "2"`: [3,8]

so two lists corresponding to the prices according to the ids
is it possible to do that in python ?

note, in fact user id are UUID type and randomly generated.

edit:  `quantity` was a mistake all data are price and id, sorry

Comment: Why is one of the items `quantity` and not `price`?

Comment: That is not valid JSON despite your editing attempts

Comment: my bad for these mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first :
you structur data : {[]}, is not supported in python.
assume your data is :

```
my_json = [
    {
      "id": "1",  
      "price": 1,   
    }, 
    {  
      "id": "1", 
      "price": 10,  
    }, 
    {
      "id": "2", 
      "quantity": 3, 
    }, 
    {   
      "id": "1", 
      "price": 10, 
    }, 
    {  
      "id": "2",   
      "price":8,  
    }, 
  ]
```

then you can achive with this:

```
results = {}
for data in my_json:
    if data.get('id') not in results:
        results[data.get('id')] = [data.get('price') or data.get('quantity')]
    else:
        results[data.get('id')].append(data.get('price') or data.get('quantity')) 
print(results)
```

output:

{'1': [1, 10, 10], '2': [3, 8]}

Comment: It's a stupid question but how to access the array directly? without having { 'id' } in before? because i want to multiply price of this array with quantity of another array

Comment: for that one you need to specify the index of that value you want.
for example :
print (my_json[3].get('price'))
output: 10

Answer (score 1):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to the rescue.

Assuming you really do have mixed `quantity`s and `price`s and you don't care about mixing them into the same list,

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "price": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "price": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "quantity": 3,
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "price": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "price": 8,
    },
]

by_id = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    item = item.copy()  # we need to mutate the item
    id = item.pop("id")
    # whatever is the other value in the dict, grab that:
    other_value = item.popitem()[1]
    by_id[id].append(other_value)

print(dict(by_id))
```

The output is

```
{'1': [1, 10, 10], '2': [3, 8]}
```

If you actually only do have `price`s, the loop is simpler:

```
by_id = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    by_id[item["id"]].append(item.get("price"))
```

or

```
by_id = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    by_id[item["id"]].append(item["price"])
```

to fail fast when the price is missing.

Comment: Upvoted, but please don't recommend naming a variable `id`. This shadows a builtin: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: @Stef Sure, but that particular builtin generally has no real-world use. IMO it's better to write readable code than code that goes through contortions to please a linter.

Comment: thanks you, and that to all to help beeginer like me !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
data = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "price": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "price": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "quantity": 3,
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "price": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "price": 8,
    }
]

result = {}
for item in data:

    try:
        result[item['id']].append(item.get('price'))
    except KeyError:
        result[item['id']] = [item.get('price')]

print(result)
```

Where `None` is put in place of the missing price for that entry, `quantity` key ignored.

Result:

```
{'1': [1, 10, 10], '2': [None, 8]}
```

Comment: Or `result.setdefault(item['id'], []).append(item;get('price'))` without the try/except

Comment: I would also add a link to the [documentation of `get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to explain its `None` default.

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop that enumerates your list (it's not JSON) in conjunction with *setdefault()* is all you need:

```
data = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "price": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "price": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "price": 3,
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "price": 10,
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "price": 8,
    }
]

dict_ = {}

for d in data:
    dict_.setdefault(d['id'], []).append(d['price'])

print(dict_)
```

**Output:**

```
{'1': [1, 10, 10], '2': [3, 8]}
```

**Note:**

This will fail (KeyError) if either 'id' or 'price' is missing from the dictionaries in the list